# How does omnibox addSuggest work in private mode?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox-addon, omnibox

I tried omnibox with the following code [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/omnibox/onInputChanged). When I trying, I temporarily loaded `manifest.json` from `about:debugging`. This worked in a normal browser, and typing `cs a` show a some suggestion.

However, this suggestion feature is not working in private mode. This did not change even if I allowed it to run in a private window.

How can I get the omnibox suggestion feature to work in private mode?

```
browser.omnibox.setDefaultSuggestion({
  description: "Type the name of a CSS property"
});

/*
Very short list of a few CSS properties.
*/
const props = [
  "animation",
  "background",
  "border",
  "box-shadow",
  "color",
  "display",
  "flex",
  "flex",
  "float",
  "font",
  "grid",
  "margin",
  "opacity",
  "overflow",
  "padding",
  "position",
  "transform",
  "transition"
];

const baseURL = "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/";

/*
Return an array of SuggestResult objects,
one for each CSS property that matches the user's input.
*/
function getMatchingProperties(input) {
  var result = [];
  for (prop of props) {
    if (prop.indexOf(input) === 0) {
      console.log(prop);
      let suggestion = {
        content: baseURL + prop,
        description: prop
      }
      result.push(suggestion);
    } else {
      if (result.length != 0) {
        return result;
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

browser.omnibox.onInputChanged.addListener((input, suggest) => {
  suggest(getMatchingProperties(input));
});

browser.omnibox.onInputEntered.addListener((url, disposition) => {
  switch (disposition) {
    case "currentTab":
      browser.tabs.update({url});
      break;
    case "newForegroundTab":
      browser.tabs.create({url});
      break;
    case "newBackgroundTab":
      browser.tabs.create({url, active: false});
      break;
  }
});
```

My `manifest.json` follows below:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "text",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "text",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "omnibox": {
    "keyword": "cs"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "bookmarks",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

---

- Windows 10
- Firefox 84.0.1 (64 bit)